# How to remove the static/index.html from URL while using React's HashRouter?

Tags: reactjs, iis, django-rest-framework, react-router

I'm using a React frontend with a DRF backend an I've hosted both on the same URL. I get the static production build for the frontend and I've put it under the static folder and when a person goes to the main URL `contoso.com` they are redirected to `contoso.com/static/index.html` where the static build is served and the different URLs can be accessed correctly using the HashRouter and reloading the page, etc works as expected but the links are like `contoso.com/static/index.html#home`, `contoso.com/static/index.html#menu`, etc. I would like to have under the main URL only as in `contoso.com/#home`, `contoso.com/#menu`. The API backend for this exists under `contoso.com/api`.
**Additional info:** Hosted on IIS v10 with wfastcgi with static folder as public

Comment: Can you share `view` that is redirecting to `/static/index.html` template

Comment: `def index(request):   
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/static/index.html')`

Comment: and build from react frontend is in the `static` folder?

Comment: yes it is @FaisalNazik

Comment: Great. You have to create a simple `TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')` I  m posting the full solution for this in Answer. Just hang on

Comment: thanks @FaisalNazik I would like to see if this would be better than the answer I already posted by moving the logic to production server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist change the TEMPLATES code from settings.py like that

```
'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static') #If index.html file is in static folder.
        ],
```

then in the `project.urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
   #...
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
]
```

Now unplug the previous view that you shared in the comment and use this URL to render index.html from the build of React frontend.

Then this will work as you wanted. `example.com/#home`

Comment: np. This will hundred per cent work. I used a similar approach in my project. check this out. https://naturalmediceclinic.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Was able to separate out the api (DRF) portion under another path on the base `web.config` file and then set a default document with the `index.html`. So I think the best option would be to move this to your production server to take care (IIS in this case)

```
<handlers>
  <add name="Django FastCGI"
        path="api"
        verb="*"
        requireAccess="Script" />
</handlers>

<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".*" mimeType="text/html" />
</staticContent>

<defaultDocument>
    <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="index.html" />
    </files>
</defaultDocument>
```